# How to display text for a section with a looping video background?

Tags: html, css, video

I am fairly new to HTML & CSS. I want to display some text in a section, with a looping video background.I tried setting the z-index to -1 but I am still unable to see the text.I also tried placing the text (`<p> Hello!</p>`) in different parts of the block but to no avail.Here is the HTML Code:

```
 <section id ="quote" style="height:200px ; width: 100%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px">
        <div>
                <video id="video" style=" position: relative ; background : cover ; background-position: center; width:100%; height:20% z-index:-1" autoplay loop muted >
                    <p color":#000000"> hello ! </p>
                    <source src="journey.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
                </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the CSS for the quote id tag :

```
#quote {
background-repeat: repeat;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
height: 20px;
```

}

Comment: I think you'll have to take the `<p>` element out of the video tag and make it a sibling (neighbour) of it. Then position it absolute inside the parent `<div>`  for the easiest way to place it where you like. Beware that absolute only works if the parent div has `position: relative` for example - as long as it's not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting the z-index to -1 but I am still unable to see the
>   text.

In this case `z-index` is not really what you need in order to create this style effect. `position:absolute;` is what you need.
By putting your `<p>` outside of the `<video>` and giving it a position absolute will do the job.

> I want to display some text in a section, with a looping video
>   background

To create a looping video as a background you'll need to set
`<video preload autoplay loop muted>`

- **preload** - We don't really need this here beacause the preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present.
  The preload attribute specifies if and how the author thinks that the video should be loaded when the page loads.
         The preload attribute allows the author to provide a hint to the    browser about what he/she thinks will lead to the best user    experience. This attribute may be ignored in some instances as mentioned above.
- **autoplay** - Autoplays the video. The video will automatically start playing as soon as it can do so without stopping.
- **loop** - It specifies that the video will start over again, every time it is finished.
- **muted** - It specifies that the audio output of the video should be muted. Assuming that you want to avoid the music/sound of the video    to be turned on for a background video

At the end, here's how the whole thing looks like:

```
<section id ="quote" style="height:200px ; width: 100%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px">
        <div class="videoContainer">
            <video autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
                    Video not supported.
            </video>
            <p class="overlayText"> hello there! This is some text.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

and your CSS

```
#quote {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.overlayText {
    color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
}   

/* This is just some CSS styling to make the video fill 100% of its div */
.videoContainer {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}   
.videoContainer video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**[Online Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q50k55b8/)**

Comment: Like mentioned in my other comment, the parent needs positioning to not be skipped by the absolute child.